# Make EFCore more performant

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

so here is my looong query and the problem is that I need every include I'm making and it's slow, but how can I make it better?

```
await _context.Set<ProductEntity>()
                .Include(i => i.Media)
                .Include(i => i.Categories)
                .Include(i => i.Reports)
                .Include(i => i.Bookmarks)
                .Include(i => i.Votes)
                .Include(i => i.User).ThenInclude(x => x.Media)
                .Include(i => i.User).ThenInclude(x => x.Categories)
                .Include(i => i.Forms)!.ThenInclude(x => x.FormField)
                .Include(i => i.Comments)!.ThenInclude(x => x.LikeComments)
                .Include(i => i.Teams)!.ThenInclude(x => x.User).ThenInclude(x => x.Media)
                .Include(i => i.VoteFields)!.ThenInclude(x => x.Votes)
                .AsNoTracking()
```

I got a tip that Select is better than Include, but I do'nt realy know how can I do that.

Comment: Just add `AsSplitQuery()` [Split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1)

Comment: Already done i startup

Comment: So, queries are splitted? Maybe you need filter / limit? How many records do you load?

Comment: Check for missing indexes

Comment: Add a where clause

Comment: Ask yourself, do you really need all of the data of the child objects? Can't you work around with just using the FK id and then getting the necessary data of the child the moment you need it?